# signing the content of an array with DSA Certificate

Tags: c, security, certificate

i never did that, so i need the basics (and where to find the libraries).

- i have a char array (binary, may contain NULL values).
- i have a PEM-File with the certificate (open key and private key). These where created with JAVAs 'keytool'.
- i have sent the open key to the recipient

what to do now? how can i sign my byte-array with the certificate and the private key which resides in the keystore.jks?

can i do this with plain C?
I have to sign a lot of those arrays autonaticaly. So my mental problem is, the password is not very secret, because my software has to know it?

Thanks for any help, or pushing me to the right website, which answers all my beginners questions.

EDITH:

now I can specify my question a bit more: I know, how to sign my message on the command line with openssl:

```
openssl dgst -dss1 -sign privkey.pem -out message.txt.sha1 message.txt
```

what I need is a C-Functioncall (I got crypto.lib and ssl.lib (Version 0.9.8h) for my legacy operating system and the tons of includes), something like

```
openssl(&my_signature, &my_signatureLen, my_message, my_messageLen, "dgst", "-dss1", "-sign", my_privkey_pem_file, my_privkey_pem_password);
```

which stores the sha1-signature into the ByteArray my_signature. Anyone who can push me into the right header files?

Thanks

EDTH 2:

I am some more steps nearer to the goal, but now I get no error, but the signing results in 0 length

```
#include "../include/openssl/dsa.h"
#include "../include/openssl/pem.h"
#include "../include/openssl/evp.h"
#include "../include/openssl/err.h"


    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
--> here any more initialization I miss?

    short fehler = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen("u:\\keys\\privkey.pem", "rb"); //unsecure
    if (fp) {
      DSA *dsa = PEM_read_DSAPrivateKey(fp, NULL, NULL, "password"); //unsecure
--> here anything more to do with the dsa-structure?!?
      if (dsa) {
--> here I am, so i cannot be so wrong
        fehler = !DSA_sign(0, data, dataLen, signatur, &signaturLen, dsa);
        if (fehler) {
--> error:0A070064:dsa routines:DSA_do_sign:data too large for key size
          ps("ERROR: no signing");
          ps(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), buf));
        }

        DSA_free(dsa);
      } else {
        ps("ERROR: no dsa");
        ps(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), buf));
      }

      fclose (fp);
    } else {
      ps("ERROR: File not open");
    }

    EVP_cleanup();
    ERR_free_strings();
```

Comment: By certifying an array, do you meaning signing the contents of the array?

Comment: You can use OpenSSL with plain C to sign the block of data using PKCS#7 format. However, if you embed the private key into your application, you need to take care of its security and if you distribute the application, chances to prevent key theft are minimal.